# How to explode mySQL column into REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a column `show_only_on` that contains value with commas `,` as `goodevening,contact,goodbye`

and I want to split the value of the `show_only_on` as below and use the `|` instead of `,`:

```
AND ('comeandsayhellothere' REGEXP('goodevening|hello|goodbye') OR show_only_on IS NULL)
```

and return **true**.

I have no luck of achieving the desired result.
This is my current line:

```
AND ('{$word}' REGEXP(show_only_on) OR show_only_on IS NULL)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can try: IN('a, b, c')

Comment: @Dmitry you are right, but I made a mistake in my question. I have updated accordingly.

Comment: What you should be focusing on is fixing your database structure to be normalized. You should never store data like this.

Comment: If you want to match `hello` in `comeandsayhellothere` you should not use word boundaries. Do you mean using a case and return `true` or `false`? See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34dc2/1

Comment: Why can't you just use `where 'comeandsayhellothere' REGEXP(REPLACE(show_only_on, ',', '|'))
   or show_only_on is null`? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=088546d01e151989718d92877e203aff

Comment: Returning only true or false and turning the comma into a pipe for the alternation might look like `CASE WHEN 'comeandsayhellothere' REGEXP(REPLACE(show_only_on, ',', '|')) OR show_only_on IS NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END`  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/537fd/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you have a column that contains words/phrases that are comma-separated, and you want to (a) check if any of these words/phrases matches a given phrase and (b) do so using regular expressions.

If so, then the essential detail is that you need to convert your comma-separated pattern into a regexp-compatible pattern. So if you have `a,b,c`, you want the equivalent regexp form of `.*(a|b|c).*`. This is an easy translation:

```
concat('.*(', replace('a,b,c', ',', '|'), ').*') -- a,b,c => .*(a|b|c).*
```

Extending this to include the matching, you then have:

```
'word' regexp concat('.*(', replace(show_only_on, ',', '|'), ').*')
```

And adding a complete sample:

```
create table t (id int not null, show_only_on varchar(32));
insert into t values (1, null), (2, 'hello'), (3, 'hi,hey,yo');
create table w (id int not null, phrase varchar(32));
insert into w values (1, 'Hi!'), (2, 'He said "hello"'), (3, 'Goodbye, world');

select w.id as phrase_id, t.id as match_id, w.phrase, t.show_only_on
  from t
  join w
    on w.phrase regexp concat('.*(', replace(t.show_only_on, ',', '|'), ').*')
       or t.show_only_on is null;
```

Results in:
[image: SQL result set]

See this online at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29897b/1).

Note that, if you go with this approach, you'll not be able to use indexes: show_only_on loses its indexability once it participates in the replace function. You might consider full-text search or separate rows for each pattern to mitigate performance concerns.

Comment: `.*` is not necessary here. `w.phrase regexp replace(t.show_only_on, ',', '|')` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is off in several places.  Consider the following updated version:

```
WHERE
    ... AND
    (contact REGEXP '[[:<:]](goodevening|hello|goodbye)[[:>:]]' OR show_only_on IS NULL)
```

`REGEXP` in MySQL is more of an operator than a function, at least in terms of syntax, so you should not be putting what follows it in parentheses.  Also, you were comparing the string literal `'contact'` against a regular expression.  This will never be true, because `contact` does not match anything in the alternation.  Finally, you should place word boundaries around the alternation, to ensure that, for example, you don't match a word like `mellohello`, which happens to contain the substring `hello`.

Comment: I made a mistake in my question. I have updated accordingly. My desired result is to return `true` if a word like mellohello is used for `$word`

Comment: @EnexoOnoma Then use `REGEXP '(goodevening|hello|goodbye)[[:>:]]'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok but in order to use it directly in mySQL I will do as the question and use the `show_only_on` column as  `AND ('{$word}' REGEXP'(show_only_on)[[:>:]]' OR show_only_on IS NULL)` that does not work

Comment: FYI the `[[:<:]]` pattern is no longer supported in MySQL 8.0. They changed the regexp library to a different implementation that does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below where condition, hope it'll help you out:

```
WHERE
... AND
('{$word}' REGEXP(REPLACE(show_only_on,',','|')) OR show_only_on IS NULL)
```